# Which JAR does Java pick for a certain import?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, shared-libraries

Dependency issues, we've all dealt with them, but I'm mostly used to C# and now working in Java so I have some questions.

Let's say I add a library to my project, called `ExtLib`.
`ExtLib` has a certain library included in its `lib`-folder, let's call it `LogLib-1.0`.

I'm using `Eclipse` and I've made a `User Library` for `ExtLib`, included its main jar file and all of the files in its `lib`-folder. So far so good.

But now I want to do some logging of my own, so I make another `User Library` and add the newer `LogLib-1.1` to it, because it has some new features I want to use.

Can I ever be sure I'm not breaking `ExtLib` this way?

I know .NET uses the Global Assembly Cache and methods like that, but I have no clue how Java handles this. I tried Googling, but didn't find much, a few mentions of the Classloader here and there, but nothing helpful.

Can anyone tell me what a proper way to deal with this issue is? Or is it no issue at all?

Comment: Partial answer: When using a normal classloader (not a custom one with unusual rules), it will load the class from the first jar file that contains it. Jar files are searched in the order they are specified on the classpath.

Comment: Okay, but when I deploy this to an application server with all of the libraries included, all of those libraries just end up in one big `lib` folder, so there's no way for me to know which it loads exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case (LogLib-1.0 and LogLib-1.1) we're dealing with the same library that is  both a direct dependency of your application, and a "transitive" dependency via the ExtLib. In this situation, dependency management can come to help.

It will probably reason that LogLib-1.1 is a backward compatible release of LogLib-1.0, and it will decide that your application can run fine using only LogLib-1.1.

In the Java world, tools like Maven, Gradle or SBT exist to help you in this. Maven is the most widespread, and other tools often are compatible with Maven.

#### Usage

To solve this situation using Maven, you would add a file called `pom.xml` to your application, stating it depends on LogLib version 1.1. That might look like this (note that this example is pure fiction):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.loglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>loglib</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The ExtLib you're using also has a pom.xml shipped with it, and it might state

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.loglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>loglib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven (or any other tool) would decide that including LogLib-1.1 is sufficient to get your application running. When using Maven, `mvn depedency:tree` helps you visualise that.

#### Deployment

With respect to the packaging / deployment question: `mvn package` will package your application to a `jar`, `war` or `ear` archive, including only the dependencies you need (and not two versions of the same lib). This makes you don't have to worry about the order in which your application server reads the jar files.

Comment: That is a bit helpful, but I'm worried about not-backwards compatible versions, which is a problem I've already experienced. I wish there was a way to tie specific versions of libraries/jars to the jars that depend on them and not let Java (or Maven) use a best guess approach. I'm just sad that no good thinking has been done about this, since it wouldn't be that hard to implement with metadata property files or something like that (like Maven does).

Comment: You can try to exclude transitive dependencies by using the `<exclude>` mechanism in Maven. This ignores the fact that ExtLib needs LogLib-1.0, so you can only hope it will working with LogLib-1.1.

Comment: Okay, but there is no definitive way to do this then.